# Web Client not receiving 404 when sent from nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send back a status of 404 to the web client when a request for a non existent record is received.

I'm using Express and MongoDB. Tested with Advanced Rest Client.

Code:

```
app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => 
{
    dbo.collection("courses").findOne({ id: parseInt(req.params.id) }, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        if (!result) { console.log('Null result sending 404'); return res.status(404); }
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

If the client sends a valid id: then the record is returned as expected.

Node Console:

```
{ _id: 5d23e6a8c922d263376442c1, id: 1, name: 'Course 1' }
```

Client:

```
    {
    "_id": "5d23e6a8c922d263376442c1",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Course 1"
    }
```

When the client sends an invalid id: the console shows the message has been sent but the client waits for ever until I stop/reset the server.

Node Console:

```
null
Null result sending 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just set status for the response, but you never send back to client anything.

Let's send something to the client.

Example, send a json object

```
return res.status(404).json({message: 'Null result sending 404'});
```

instead of `return res.status(404);`

Comment: As described in the answer or res.status(404).send('Null ...');